# python neo4j not getting other relationships

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

I am using neo4j library in python and writing cypher queries there itself.

Here is a piece of my code :

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth
from config import bolt_url,auth_id,auth_pass

driver = GraphDatabase.driver(bolt_url, auth=basic_auth(auth_id, auth_pass))
session = driver.session()


def get_some_data(limit=25) :
    query = 'MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) \
            RETURN n,r,m LIMIT ' + str(limit)
    return session.run(query)

result_some_data = get_some_data(limit=4)
gen = result_some_data.records()

for record in gen :    
    n = record['n']
    m = record['m']
    r = record['r']
    print()
    print(n)
    print(m)
    print(r)
```

And this is what I get :

```
<Node id=68757 labels={'ContentItem'} properties={'id': '1'}>
<Node id=72389 labels={'Person'} properties={'name': 'Tony'}>
<Relationship id=288942 start=72389 end=68757 type='Inside' properties={}>

<Node id=68757 labels={'ContentItem'} properties={'id': '1'}>
<Node id=72390 labels={'Person'} properties={'name': 'Bruce'}>
<Relationship id=288943 start=72390 end=68757 type='Inside' properties={}>

<Node id=68757 labels={'ContentItem'} properties={'id': '1'}>
<Node id=79758 labels={'Organization'}l properties={'name':'Oscorp'}>
<Relationship id=278985 start=79758 end=68757 type='Inside' properties={}>

<Node id=68758 labels={'ContentItem'} properties={'id': '2'}>
<Node id=79759 labels={'Organization'} properties={'name': 'STAR Labs'}>
<Relationship id=278986 start=79759 end=68758 type='Inside' properties={}>
```

PS : ignore the name properties, I have changed them.

When I run the same cypher query on neo4j browser, I get this graph:

[image: Graph from neo4j browser]

In the image, you can see that there are 4 other relationships that are we don't get in python, namely the 2 `linkedWith` and the 2 `RelatedTo` relationships are missing.

Now, I know that the neo4j is matching the requested relations and return them only, but coming to my question (Finally!), is there a way to get these 'other' 4 relationships as well?

Comment: You are limiting the return to four (i.e. `(limit=4)` ) - no? The browser will complete extra relationships via the `Connect result nodes` attribute in the Browser Settings of the left nav.

Comment: Now I know why the browser shows the other connections. Thank you. Is there a way to send this setting from python and receive the other relationships?

Comment: No, the browser basically has additional overhead. It turns around and fetches all of the other relationships between the nodes that are returned in the result set of the query. If you want your query to return those things you need to ask for them. Your query is completely open ended and just looking for all unordered pairs of connected nodes in your database. You will get the same nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to get all of the relationships between the nodes in your specific database you could use the following query. Note this will only work in this version of your database. It is built using the node ids from your returned data. Also note the direction added to the query that way you will only return each pair of nodes focuses on a relationship once instead of twice.

```
WITH [68757,72389,68757,72390,68757,79758,68758,79759] as nodes
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
WHERE id(n) in nodes
AND id(m) in modes
RETURN n,r,m LIMIT
```

Comment: In this version of my database, there are tens of thousands of nodes, I just limited my search to 4 relations

Comment: Yup... i saw that :)

Comment: So I am running 2 cypher queries from python, first one is same as in question, to get the nodes, and the second one from your answer, where the array is obtained from the result of first query